# Generics, static Methods and Extension

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an abstract Class:

```
 public abstract class BaseBean {

     public static String getTableName(){
        return "base";
     }
 }
```

And I have several Classes extending BaseBean, for Example:

```
public class User extends BaseBean {

    public static String getTableName(){
        return "user";
    }
}
```

(I think you already smell the Problem here)

Furthermore I have a generic Class:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends BaseBean> {

    public String getName(){
        return T.getTableName();
    }

}
```

What I want to do:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        GenericClass<User> userClass = new GenericClass<>();
        String name = userClass.getName();
    }
}
```

Obvilously I want the String name to be "user" but it is "base". 
I searched a lot, and I know that I cannot overwrite static methods, but I don't know how to achieve it otherwise.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can not override static methods

Comment: Basically static methods can not be overridden. That is `GenericClass` will always use the `getTableName` method from `BaseBean`

Comment: I know, but this was not the question.
Question is: How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Does it really have to be a static method? You could do it with reflection, but that would be extremely ugly.

Comment: I want to get the name from T, so I thought it needs to be static.
As you see, a don't have an instance of T (User in this case)

Comment: It looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you explain why you need such method?

Comment: You could try to use annotations and get the annotated value from your class object using reflection for example. However the snippets you posted very much look like you're trying to reinvent the wheel and should have a look at JPA.